# Which Dependency Injection should i implement in android

Tags: android

In Kotlin which dependency injection i should go for like Koin or Dagger.
I am using Android architecture component as design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the production level(over than 15 activities/fragments, personally.), you definitely use **Dagger** than Koin. Koin isn't Dependency Injector, is a Service Locator.

But in a personal project or small-level application, you can use **Koin** instead of Dagger because **Dagger can be too verbose**.

Although I using Kotlin in production level, I prefer **Dagger** than Koin on both of personal and production level. Because Service locators is an inferior design pattern on Android and [violates encapsulation](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation/)

But if you get into this concept for the first time, I think it will be easier for **Koin** to adapt.

Comment: I have seen that Koin is lightweight framework to add dependancy injection. There Doc Link : https://insert-koin.io/

Comment: Strictly speaking, Koin is Service Locator, not dependency injection. (It just adds a little magic.) In personal opinion, it's best to **decide on the size of the app to implement**. If there are more than 50 activity or fragments, and there are many ViewModels or Repositories that need to be connected(injected) to it, Koin will be a very tough experience.